# How to disable query execution on componentWillReceiveProps lifecycle with react-apollo?

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo

Is it possible to somehow disable execution of query in `componentWillReceiveProps` when react-apollo HOC `graphql` is used? To illustrate what I'm trying to do.

I've got route `/:albumSlug/photos/:photoId` which will open photo detail page with photo in album according to url. This page will also fetch, 10 photos before and after this photo with photoId. Now when user navigate to next photo, i will check if there is more than 5 photo preloaded and if yes, i will skip this query, if now i will execute `fetchMore` query over photos and merge data together.

The problem is if i use graphql HOC it will fire single query for every `componentWillReceiveProps`. Is it possible to somehow disable it? Or any other solution?

Only solution i came out was to wrap component returned with graphql to simple component, which will handle this skip state and use `skip` options in query option, but I somehow really don't like this solution.

UPDATE:
Well, it is just idea, but query look like this:

```
album(id: $albumId) {
  current:photoById(id: $photoId) {
    ...photo
  }
  previous: photos(before: $photoId, limit: 10) {
    ...photo
  }
  next: photos(after: $photoId, limit: 10) {
    ...photo
  }
}
```

I'm then using props mapping like this:

```
photos: [...album.previous, album.current, ...album.next]
```

to transform it to array in which i can find photo. I use this to render navigation too and my idea was to use `fetchMore` function and merge it to this page. Don't know if it will work I'm experimenting little bit.

Comment: You can use the `noFetch` option to make sure data is only loaded from the cache, and doesn't hit the server. I'm not sure exactly how you are planning on determining whether or not the query should be loaded, can you give more detail?

Comment: @stubailo added comment, i hope it will exaplin my idea little bit more

Answer (score 0):

With Apollo 1.0 RC you can use FetchPolicy.